# Will a basic pgRouting/OSM data setup allow me to calculate travel-times?

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting

I have a PostGIS database and I need to figure out a quick (in terms of setup) way of calculating the travel-time between points corresponding to geocoded addresses taking into account the route and speed-limits involved. It looks like the pgRouting extension combined with OSM data is going to be my best bet (although please correct me if there's a better alternative). Before I start going down that route, however, I was wondering if someone could just confirm whether or not I'm going to need any additional steps/data/software in order to do what I need? The points I have are within the US states of PA, NJ and DE.

Comment: What exactly do you need?

Comment: Given two features, I need to get the travel-time between them, taking into account the route itself and the speed-limits involved.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include any extra info rather than adding it as a comment.

Comment: Since you're asking for additional steps, what steps do you already have?  Do those steps worK?

Comment: OK, I edited the question to include my clarification.

I'm asking if I would need any additional steps on top of simply installing pgRouting and importing OSM data. I haven't done that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pgRouting the the shortest path function(s) return the route with the lowest cost between two points. If your `cost` attribute is "time", then your shortest path will be the quickest route.

I recommend you to start with the pgRouting workshop, which explains about variable costs as well: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/advanced.html

Comment: Thanks for this. Having gone through the workshop, it looks like I can accomplish what I need with the OSM data by using the fact that the cost stored is the length and that each tuple in the 'ways' table has an associated road-class. The road-classes allow max speed-limits to be stored so it should be possible to calculate approximate travel-time based on that.